# with javascript onclick add classname to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to achieve with javascript something like when i clink on any of thumbnail (btn-1, btn-2 and btn-3) the specific class should be add to box div dynamically.

my code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ukh/5drm90fq/5/)

```js
document.getElementById('btn-1').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('box').className = 'bg-1';
}
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: darkgray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#btn-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#btn-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#btn-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.bg-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.bg-3 {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>

<div class="thumbnail" id="btn-1"></div>
<div class="thumbnail" id="btn-2"></div>
<div class="thumbnail" id="btn-3"></div>
```

Comment: So what is your question? What isn't working specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of bothering with classes, use simply a `data-` attribute like: `data-bg="#f00"`

```js
$('[data-bg]').css('background', function () {
  $(this).on('click', () => $('#box').css('background', this.dataset.bg));
  return this.dataset.bg;
});
```

```css
#box {
  background: darkgray;
  width: 120px; height: 120px;
}

[data-bg] {
  width: 30px; height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<div data-bg="red"></div>
<div data-bg="#00f"></div>
<div data-bg="rgb(255,0,180)"></div>
<div data-bg="linear-gradient(to right, #E100FF, #7F00FF)"></div>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: how I can use gradient colors with [data-color]? because i tried but its not working!

My Gradient color:

background: #7F00FF;

/* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #E100FF, #7F00FF);
 /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */

background: linear-gradient(to right, #E100FF, #7F00FF);
/* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

Answer (score 1):

You javascript is working, but your CSS isn't.

You need to add !important as follows to .bg-1, .bg-2 and .bg-3

```
.bg-1 {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Otherwise the id styling is taking preference over the class styling

You can see the classname is being added if you right click on the grey div and choose inspect element in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use jquery .addClass() function:

```
$('.myButton').addClass('myNewClass');
```

The function would probably look something like this:

```
$(function () {
     $('.thumbnail').click(function() {
         $('#box').addClass($(this).attr('id'));
     });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the thumbnails as an array, and then iterate through the array and dynamically add an event listener to each, which will add the desired className to box when clicked:

```
var thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail');

Array.from(thumbnails).forEach(function(thumbnail) {
    var id = thumbnail.id;
    thumbnail.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('box').className = id.replace('btn', 'bg')
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry about that, it's fixed now